# Why "else" doesn't work in my if statement code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Simply want the else to work and apply the original opacity which is 1, but why isn't it working?

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container").children;
let contArr = [...container];


contArr.forEach( item => {
        item.addEventListener("click", function handleClick() {

            if (item.style.opacity = "1") {
                item.style.opacity = "0.5";
            } else {
                item.style.opacity = "1";
            }

        })});
```

```css
.container {
    line-height: 0;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0;
    column-fill: balance;
  }
  
  .container img {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .container img:hover {
    scale: 1.1;
    transition: 0.5s;
    left: 120%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .viewer {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5);

    /* transition: 1s; */
  }

  .closeViewer {
    color: #000;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" id="container">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a31/colorful-umbrella-1176220.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/9e6/abstract-polygonal-low-poly-photos-texture-3-636190.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/aa8/evening-01-1055813.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3437/3403778548_15f48ab99e_b.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/25/01/22/cat-2536662_960_720.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/01/19/35/wolf-3577956_960_720.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://live.staticflickr.com/3437/3403778548_15f48ab99e_b.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/25/01/22/cat-2536662_960_720.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/01/19/35/wolf-3577956_960_720.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a31/colorful-umbrella-1176220.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/9e6/abstract-polygonal-low-poly-photos-texture-3-636190.jpg">
            <img class="img"src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/aa8/evening-01-1055813.jpg">
    </div>

  
    <div class="viewer" id="viewer">
        <button class="closeViewer" id="closeViewer" onclick="closeViewer()">X</button>
    </div>


    <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `==` instead of `=` for conditional statement. For checking exact value of something equals to something, try using `===`. It is more precise. See why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons#:~:text=The%20strict%20equality%20operator%20(%20%3D%3D%3D,same%20to%20be%20considered%20equal.&text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20will%20compare,doing%20any%20necessary%20type%20conversions.

Comment: I actually did before I asked but the problem is there is one more click before changes happen for the first click. why? 

  if (item.style.opacity == "1") {
                item.style.opacity = "0.5";
            } else {
                item.style.opacity = "1";
            }

Answer (score 1):

You have to do one more click to start with because noone has set the style.opacity of the element. Yes, there is a setting of opacity in the style sheet but this hasn't set anything in the style attribute.

So change the test so the first time (when the style.opacity doesn't have either 1 or 0.5 as a value) you set it:

```
        if (item.style.opacity != "0.5") {
            item.style.opacity = "0.5";
        } else {
            item.style.opacity = "1";
        }
```

Comment: finally it works. being a self learner is really confusing. thank you guys.